# How to connect to AWS EC2 via SSH

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, gitlab-ci

I want to deploy my backend on AWS EC2 via gitlab-ci, but ssh doesn't work. How can I connect to my EC2 instance?

```
image: docker:latest
...
deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "$EC2_SSH_KEY" > "key.pem"
    - chmod 777 key.pem
    - apk update && apk add openssh
    - ssh -tt -i "key.pem" ec2-user@....compute.amazonaws.com
```

Error

```
$ ssh -tt -i "key.pem" ec2-user@....compute.amazonaws.com
Host key verification failed.
```

Comment: do  not use 777 for ssh keys, try to set them to 644 or better 600

Comment: Set them to 600 specifically. They must be accessible only to owner.

Comment: I suggest that you also tell what you have tried and didn't work. You can find previous similar questions by searching with your error message and then edit your question with some more details about what you did but didn't work.

Comment: Are using the same key which is configured to the instance on aws?

Comment: @Adrian that depends on if the sshd server is configured with StrictModes enabled.

Comment: “Host key verification failed” is explicit, you need to accept the host keys or disable host key checking in your connection options (i.e.: -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no). Ref. i.e.: https://askubuntu.com/questions/87449/how-to-disable-strict-host-key-checking-in-ssh

Comment: Thanks to @masseyb it works. I added this option to ssh and after that gitlab-ci told me that I need to set the key to 600.

Comment: @laprof ssh complaining about incorrect permissions on the files suggests that StrictModes is enabled on the server - either disable StrictModes or set the correct permissions on the keys. Happy ssh’ing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error "Host key verification failed" is explicit - you need to accept the server's host keys before the connection can be established OR you need to disable host key checking (i.e. `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@host`).

If the `ssh` server is configured with `StrictModes` then `sshd` will complain if the ownership / permissions of the files are incorrect, you can set the correct permissions with i.e.:

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

For additional information regarding the `StrictHostKeyChecking` and `StrictModes` options ref. https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sshd_config(5)